# show function does not converge as h tends to 0

Tags: convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I need to show that $3h\sin(1/h) - \cos(1/h)$ does not have a limit as $h \to 0$. I'm fairly new to the epsilon delta proofs and am not sure how to do it for this question, would someone be able to walk me through it please?

Comment: usually in these cases you try to find two sub-sequences with different limits. With trig functions this is usually not that hard - try to see for example what happens when $h_n = \frac{1}{n}$ (you need to modify this example to get the desired result).

Comment: A more specific hint: take $h_n$ going to zero so that $\cos(1/h_n)$ will bounce around, say between $-1$ and $1$. Then the argument is that $f(h_n)$ would converge to $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h)$ if the latter existed, but the former will not converge at all, so the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I'll have a go with that now

Comment: Thanks all, I think I've done it now. I really overcomplicated it in my head lol

Answer (score 0):

#### We have to prove $\lim_{x \to 0} (3hsin(\frac{1}{h}) - cos(\frac{1}{h}))$= Limit does not exist

So,

#### 1).Lets prove $\lim_{x \to 0} 3hsin(\frac{1}{h})=0$

$$-1\leq sin\frac{1}{h}\leq 1$$

$$-3h\leq 3hsin\frac{1}{h}\leq 3h$$

$$0=\lim_{h \to 0}(-3h)\leq 3h\lim_{h \to 0}(sin\frac{1}{h})\leq \lim_{h \to 0}(3h)=0$$

By sandwich theorem we get, $$3h\lim_{h \to 0}sin\frac{1}{h}=0$$

#### 2).Lets prove $\lim_{x \to 0} cos(\frac{1}{h})=Does  \: not \: exist$

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \;  \exists \delta \; s.t \;  0<\left | x \right |  < \delta \mapsto |cos\frac{1}{h}-L|<\varepsilon$$

Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$,

$$0<\left | x \right |  < \delta \mapsto |cos\frac{1}{h}-L|<\frac{1}{2}$$

So lets **assume** that, $$\lim_{x \to 0} cos(\frac{1}{h})=L \; \in \mathbb{R}$$

Let $$x_{1}=\frac{1}{2n\pi} \; \;  (n\in Z^{+})\; \; and \; \; x_{2}=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi } \; \;  (n\in Z^{+})$$
So we have to get range of n,
$$0<|\frac{1}{2n\pi +\pi}| < |\frac{1}{2n\pi }|<\delta$$
$$0<\frac{1}{|2n\pi| }<\delta$$
So we get,
$$0<\frac{1}{|2\pi\delta| }<n\; \;  (n\in Z^{+})$$

Now,
$$|cos(2n\pi)-L|=|cos(x_{1})-L|=|1-L|<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \mathbf{A}$$
$$|cos(2n\pi+\pi)-L|=|cos(x_{2})-L|=|-1-L|=|1+L|<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \mathbf{B}$$
By **A** + **B** we get,
$$|1-L|+|1+L|< 1$$
$$|(1-L)+(1+L)|\leq |1-L|+|1+L|< 1$$
$$2\leq |1-L|+|1+L|< 1$$
$$2<1 \; \;\; \; (\therefore This \;is \;a \;contradiction)$$

So our assumption is false, Therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} cos(\frac{1}{h})$ has no limit.

#### So $\lim_{x \to 0} (3hsin(\frac{1}{h}) - cos(\frac{1}{h}))=\lim_{x \to 0} 3hsin(\frac{1}{h})-\lim_{x \to 0} cos(\frac{1}{h})=$Limit does not exist